# Prawn::Document.generate throws unknown error in jruby on Windows Server 2012

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, prawn

I'm testing prawn(1.3.0) in jruby(1.7.4) on Windows 2012 Server.

This simple document creation test throws an unknown error.

Does anyone have any experience with prawn, jruby and Windows? Any help with troubleshooting this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'prawn'
Prawn::Document.generate("prawn_test.pdf") do
  text "Hello world."
end
```

---

```
SystemCallError: Unknown error - Unknown Error (20047) - -1
         size at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:1081   render_body at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/document_state.rb:69
         each at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/object_store.rb:70
         each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1617
         each at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/object_store.rb:69 render_body at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/document_state.rb:68 render_body at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/renderer.rb:192
       render at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pdf-core-0.4.0/lib/pdf/core/renderer.rb:157
       render at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/prawn-1.3.0/lib/prawn/document.rb:356   render_file at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/prawn-1.3.0/lib/prawn/document.rb:364
         open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1148   render_file at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/prawn-1.3.0/lib/prawn/document.rb:364
     generate at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/prawn-1.3.0/lib/prawn/document.rb:143
       (root) at C:\Users\hshields\WebApps\taskmodules\prawn_test.rb:3 [Finished in 6.4s]
```

Comment: Updating jruby to 1.7.18 resolved this issue. HS